# CssSelector multiple, Arquillian Graphene

Tags: java, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian

i'm using Arquillian Graphene to get an element, and i want to be sur the get this one, becaus there is a lot of element with the same class and the id is generated so i can't really use it.

So, i'm looking for something like :

```
@FindBy(css="input[id*='contactPerson'] and [type='text']")
```

PS : i can't try it for the moment, that's why i ask that question, thank you for understanding.

---

EDIT :

This is how my input is generated.

```
<input id="contactPerson:contactPerson_input" 
       name="contactPerson:contactPerson_input" 
       type="text" 
       class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover"
       value="James Bond" role="textbox"aria-multiline="false">
```

Marco

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following if css is snot working.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@value,'James Bond')]")
```

**EDIT**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete-input ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') and contains(@type,'text')]")
```

Comment: It's a good answer but i forgot to say that value is the name of the current user, so i'll match for James Bond, but not for another user.